# How to retrieve the page load timeout through Selenium and Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pageloadtimeout

Is there any method in Python + Selenium for retrieving the webdriver's current page load timeout?

I know to use `set_page_load_timeout()` and examining the Chromedriver logs shows that this modified its internal state so I am wondering if there's way to query for it?

Alternatively, I will simply save the value on my side of the code. The retrieval would be helpful to verify that the timeout was successfully set and later on that it's still the same.

Comment: There's no reason to believe that if you set it properly that it wouldn't be set and stay the same unless you set it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize the *WebDriver* it is configured with a *default* **`page_load_timeout`** of **300000** *seconds* which you can extract from the **capabilities** *dictionary* as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  dict = driver.capabilities['timeouts']
  print(dict["pageLoad"])
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  300000
  ```